# ckeditor - can not edit inserted links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using the ckeditor in my web-app.

When i try to edit inserted links using the context-menu or double-click, the URL input-field appears empty.

My inserted link looks like this one:

```
<a data-cke-saved-href="www.google.de" href="www.google.de">www.google.de</a>
```

How it should work - have a look here:
[ckeditor demo - edit inserted links](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Thank's for help

**UPDATE**

## ckeditor config.js

```
 /**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

// The following value defines which File Browser connector and Quick Upload
// "uploader" to use. It is valid for the default implementaion and it is here
// just to make this configuration file cleaner.
// It is not possible to change this value using an external file or even
// inline when creating the editor instance. In that cases you must set the
// values of LinkBrowserURL, ImageBrowserURL and so on.
// Custom implementations should just ignore it.
var _FileBrowserLanguage    = 'asp' ;   // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | perl | php | py
var _QuickUploadLanguage    = 'asp' ;   // asp | aspx | cfm | lasso | php

// Don't care about the following two lines. It just calculates the correct connector
// extension to use for the default File Browser (Perl uses "cgi").
var _FileBrowserExtension = _FileBrowserLanguage == 'perl' ? 'cgi' : _FileBrowserLanguage ;
var _QuickUploadExtension = _QuickUploadLanguage == 'perl' ? 'cgi' : _QuickUploadLanguage ;


CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {


    config.contentsCss = CKEDITOR.basePath + 'css/editorarea.css' ;
    config.defaultLanguage = 'de' ;
    config.contentsLangDirection = 'ltr';

    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'Maximize' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'doctools', 'document' ] }
    ];


    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'mycustombrowser-url';

    config.removeButtons = 'Iframe,Anchor,Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,Form,Checkbox,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Radio,Strike,Language,BidiRtl,BidiLtr,Image,Flash,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Styles,Format,Font,FontSize,TextColor,BGColor,ShowBlocks,About,Blockquote,CreateDiv,Indent,Outdent,Subscript,Superscript,RemoveFormat,Find,Replace,SelectAll';


    config.smiley_path  = CKEDITOR.basePath  + 'images/smiley/msn/' ;
    config.smiley_images = ['regular_smile.gif','sad_smile.gif','wink_smile.gif','teeth_smile.gif','confused_smile.gif','tounge_smile.gif','embaressed_smile.gif','omg_smile.gif','whatchutalkingabout_smile.gif','angry_smile.gif','angel_smile.gif','shades_smile.gif','devil_smile.gif','cry_smile.gif','lightbulb.gif','thumbs_down.gif','thumbs_up.gif','heart.gif','broken_heart.gif','kiss.gif','envelope.gif'] ;
    config.smiley_columns = 8;
    config.filebrowserWindowHeight = CKEDITOR.config.height  * 0.7 ;        // 70%
    config.filebrowserWindowWidth = CKEDITOR.config.width * 0.7 ;       // 70%;
};

CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name; 
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition; 
    var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();

    if(dialogName == 'link') { 

           dialogDefinition.onLoad = function ( ) { 
            //var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
            //elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','protocol'); 
            //elem.default = '<andere>';
        }; 

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () { 
            dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
            //dialog.hidePage( 'target' ); // via config 
            //dialog.hidePage( 'advanced' ); // via config 
            elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','anchorOptions');    
            elem.getElement().hide();
            elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','emailOptions'); 
            elem.getElement().hide();
        }; 
    }

});
```

## Implementation:

```
<textarea type="text" name="ArticleTextPart_text" style="height:200px;">{=ArticleTextPart_text}</textarea>
```

Replacement- JS-Function:

```
function replaceTextAreasByWYSIWYGEditor() {
    var firstCK = null;
    var allTextAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    for (var i=0; i < allTextAreas.length; i++) {
        var cssClasses = allTextAreas[i].className;     
        if (cssClasses && cssClasses.indexOf("nowysiwyg") >= 0) {
            continue;
        }
        var name = allTextAreas[i].id;
        // alert (name);
        if (!name) {
            name = allTextAreas[i].name;
        }
        var height = allTextAreas[i].style.height;              
        var width = allTextAreas[i].style.width;
        var tabix = allTextAreas[i].getAttribute("tabindex");

        editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
        if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }

        CKEDITOR.replace( name,
        {
            basePath : pathprefix + "/pathTo/ckeditor/",
            height : ((!height) ?  100 : height),
            width : ((!width) ?  607 : width),
            toolbar : ((fckmode != null && fckmode == 'expert') ?  "Default" : "Basic"),
            toolbarStartupExpanded : true,
            resize_enabled : false,
            removePlugins : 'elementspath'
        });

        editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];

        if (tabix == 1) {
            firstCK = editor;
        }
    }
    if (firstCK != null) {
        firstCK.Focus();
    }
}
```

## Web-Inspector

ckeditor - "edit link" context-menu link:

```
<a id="cke_133" class="cke_menubutton cke_menubutton__link cke_menubutton_off cke_menubutton__link" href="javascript:void('Link bearbeiten')" title="Edit link" tabindex="-1" _cke_focus="1" hidefocus="true" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="false" aria-disabled="false" onmouseover="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(109,3);" onmouseout="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(110,3);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(111,3); return false;"><span class="cke_menubutton_inner"><span class="cke_menubutton_icon"><span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__link_icon" style="background-image:url('http://www.mywww.com/icons.png?t=FACH');background-position:0 -1248px;background-size:auto;"></span></span><span class="cke_menubutton_label">Edit link</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Can you post a bare bones code sample of your page with the ckeditor textarea and your config? Also, do you see any errors in the browser console when loading the page or when double clicking a hyperlink?

Comment: @Atzmon. I have edit my post. Hope this helps. There are no errors in the console of the web-inspector. Tested with chrome & firefox. Ckeditor Demo works but my ckeditor implementation not. My current fckeditor implementation, which i try to upgrade, works as well.

Comment: If you create the same page but with only one textarea, does the problem occur?

Comment: @Atzmon: Good idea but the problem occur as well. No console error nothing

Comment: I have still the same behavior. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out, updating the ckeditor to version 4.5.10 (latest version) solved the issue.